# Batch : Rename a file according to the dir command

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, dir, batch-rename

I have an issue to rename a file to a result of a dir.
Example :

I have a folder name **candidate** in C drive and inside candidate folder there is below files :

1. something.txt
2. everything.doc
3. onething.bmp

When I **dir** , I will get the listing of the files.

In the folder will always be 1 txt file and 1 bmp file

How can I rename the BMP file so it will have the same name as the TXT file assuming that I use **dir *.txt**

In the example above how can I change ***onething.bmp*** to ***something.bmp***

Thanks in advance for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%X in ("*.txt") do (
 for %%Y in ("*.bmp") do (
  echo ren %%Y %%~nX%%~xY
 )
)
```

remove the `echo` if the output is what you need.

For explanation of `%%~nX` etc. see `for /?`

Comment: Thanks @Stephan...
I am still not able to get it right. Here is what I did

:copyFiles
copy *.txt c:\MY\%username%\%3\
copy *.doc c:\MY\%username%\%3\
copy *.bmp c:\MY\%username%\%3\
goto renameBMP

:renameBMP
cd /d c:\MY\%username%\%3
for %%X in ("*.txt") do (
 for %%Y in ("*.bmp") do (
  ren %%Y %%~nX%%~xY
 )
)
pause
goto exit

Outcome does not rename the bmp as same as the txt file name.
There is only 1 txt file and 1 bmp file

Comment: `copy .txt` won't copy, but give an error instead (use `copy *.txt`)  Also in `for %%X in (".txt")...` the wildcard is missing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%X in ("*.txt") DO (SET txtName=%%X)
FOR %%X in ("*.bmp") DO (SET bmpName=%%X)
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%X IN ("%txtName%") DO (
    REN %bmpName% %%X.bmp
)
```

This will only work if the bat file is located in the same folder as the txt and the bmp files. If it's located somewhere else you will have to adjust the path.
If there are several bmp/txt files in the foleder, only the "last" files will be processed.

Comment: Thanks @Michaels

Sorry to inform that the files are not as same as the batch location thus your coding do not give the result that I want but really really appreciate the assistance